# How to start recording data at 00:08:00?

Tags: excel, vba

Couple of macros are used. In then "ThisWorkbook" module, paste:

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean) 
     'Stop execution when workbook closes
    On Error Resume Next 
    Application.OnTime Heure, "Calcul", , False 
End Sub 

Private Sub Workbook_Open() 
     'start execution when workbook opens
    Application.OnTime Now + TimeValue("00:01:00"), "Calcul" 
End Sub
```

In  module :

```
VB:
Public Heure As Date 
Sub Calcul() 
    Heure = Now + TimeValue("00:01:00") 
    Application.OnTime Heure, "Calcul" 
    Range("B65536").End(xlUp).Offset(1) = [A1] 
End Sub
```

Cell A1 will be copied every minute in column B (starting B2). Now I want this function to start at 00:08:00 but wasn't able to achieve it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As long as the workbook can remain open, the below code:

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open() 
     'start execution when workbook opens
     Application.OnTime Now + TimeValue("00:01:00"), "Calcul" 
End Sub
```

Can be replaced with the following:

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open() 
     'start execution at 8 AM when workbook opens
     If Hour(Now()) < 8 Then
         ' If it is before 8 AM
         Application.OnTime Int(Now()) + TimeSerial(8, 0, 0), "Calcul"
         Else
         ' Otherwise begin 8 AM the next day
         Application.OnTime Int(Now()) + 1 + TimeSerial(8, 0, 0), "Calcul"
     End if      
End Sub
```

Comment: now for starting at 00:08:15 i used this code is that right
    Private Sub Workbook_Open()
     'start execution at 8 AM when workbook opens
     If Hour(Now()) < 8 & Minute(Now()) < 5 Then
         ' If it is before 8 AM
         Application.OnTime Int(Now()) + TimeSerial(8, 5, 0), "Calcul"
         Else
         ' Otherwise begin 8 AM the next day
         Application.OnTime Int(Now()) + 1 + TimeSerial(8, 5, 0), "Calcul"
     End If
End Sub

Comment: "&" is used to "concatenate" so "AND" should be used, instead, in your if-then statement.  Also, if you want 15 minutes past the hour, you should use 15 instead of 5.  But yes, that is the idea in general.